# Data Structure to store duplicate lines and their count

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am processing a very huge files (containing many many millions of small lines. Total size of files I need to process is about 200 GBs) using Java. I am looking for best way to store the duplicate lines and their count. For example, if my file is following:

```
Chicago
New York
Chicago
LA
Chicago
LA
```

Then I want to store the following information:

```
Chicago 3
New York 1
LA 2
```

I think the best way is a `HashMap<String, Int>`. However, since there are millions of values, while processing a line: I need to search the map whether that line is already present in the map. If yes, then I need to increment the count by 1 and then process the next line.

Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- On map:

> I need to search the map whether that line is already present in the map. If yes, then I need to increment the count by 1 and then process the next line.
>
> Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Actually, checking "whether that line is already present in the map" is quite fast operation (in fact a constant one) due to the way [`HashMaps`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) work:

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the
>   elements properly among the buckets.

- On file:

You need to store a value (the count) for a key (the line) so you can't avoid using a map-like structure. You also need to check each line in the file so you know whether that kind of line was already stored/read. So you have to parse them one by one

Comment: @ the author and anyone curious: HashMaps are actually Hash Tables - that's the common (language/technology independent) name for similar map-like data structures that use Hash functions for keys. So search for HT if you want to know more details on how HashMaps work

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most efficient way to achive your goal. No need for extra search, just read and increment:

```
Integer count = map.get(word);
map.put(word, count == null ? 1 : ++count);
```

Not faster but a shorter way to do the same with ConcurrentHashMap:

```
m.compute(word, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use the proper terminology. By "search", I meant using the `get()` method. So basically, what I am doing is efficient!

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `map.put(word, count == null ? 1 : ++count)`?

Answer (score 1):

As the file size is very big, [**ConcurrentHashMap**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) should be a good collection to use. It will reduce your processing (get/put) significantly.

Answer (score 0):

*HashMap* is ok, but since your data size is too large, I suggest you go for a NoSQL solution, *HBase* for example.